# See all information about all processes, daemons, etc. running on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, process, maintenance

I like to view information about all processes (including every daemon etc etc) that are running on Mac OS X.

**I use:**

```
sudo ps -A
```

Update: I also tried Activity Monitor as suggested by Alex.

**My questions:**

- Is there a better way?
- How do I identify which of processes are native (shipped with the OS), belong to my installed applications (I.e. Thunderbird, Parallels Desktop etc) or cannot be classified?
- How do I find out which processes sending information into the Internet or local network?

**Background:**
The system responds slowly and the Terminal tends to hang up after I start the Terminal application for the first time after start up. I tried to remove unused applications, run all of Maintenance.app's maintenance scripts, disabled startup items, disabled all eye candy, bought max. RAM - but still everything is slow.

Comment: In regards to the Terminal slow down check: http://superuser.com/questions/31403/how-can-i-speed-up-terminal-app-or-iterm-on-mac-osx

Comment: I agree that many times Activity Monitors simply isn't good enough for finding bottlenecks and performance issues and I'd appreciate a good app for that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not try using **[Activity Monitor](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1342)**? It's buit-in, has a GUI and offers plenty of information.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Comment: thanks! Yes, the application is more comfortable than ps. Unfortunately I cannot find any hint for a process or application that eats up the system's performance.

Comment: If it's not there, then maybe it's something else. Look at memory usage, disk activity and usage; there has to be at least a clue about what is hitting your system performance.

Comment: The problem appears when I start a new process. Most noticeable, when I start the Terminal: The terminal is hanging while trying to execute my .profile file.  
  
Inside .profile I define several functions (in bash script). I guess they might be eating up my memory. I uncommented them and if needed, I will post them at stackoverflow (since they are related to programing).

Comment: Ok. Hope you can actually solve your problem! :)

Answer (score 1):

If I were trying to find out why Terminal or bash were slow at starting up, I would first double-check for directories in PATH that are network-based (do you have any AFP or NFS shares mounted on your machine? Not so common on desktop Macs, but that's a 'Unix-SA-101'-taught cause.)

I would then try sourcing the script into a separately executed shell, to see if they were slow then. I might also either log in remotely, via SSH, or use a second different 'term' type program, to execute 'sudo dtruss -d -f -p ' on the newly started Terminal.app process ID and see if there were any clues there as to what it was busy doing (or not doing!)
If I could reproduce the problem just by starting a bash process, then I'd dtruss that directly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're running some variant of Leopard, this script will dump out a big long list of all the aftermarket system augmentations it can find on your system:

http://www.khiltd.com/Downloads/ConsultantsCanary.tar.gz

And this one will dump out a big long list of all the processes with open network connections (very, very slowly):

http://www.khiltd.com/Downloads/lwt.sh

The first one is a double-clickable AppleScript wrapper, the second must be run from the command line and may spew a few errors as well under 10.6. Neither actually does anything beyond reporting the files' existence, so if you want something removed you have to do it yourself.

Comment: None of this 2 URL works.