# On Mac OS X how can I see how much memory is being used by what programs?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, virtual-memory

On Mac OS X  how can I see how much memory is being used by what programs?

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/43157/see-all-information-about-all-processes-daemons-etc-running-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the Activity Monitor application. It is located in `/Applications/Utilities/Activity Monitor.app`. And here is a screenshot with the columns for memory usage highlighted:[image: Activity Monitor Screenshot]

Comment: +1 - short, sweet, and correct. Including a screenshot might enhance your answer though!

Comment: @nhinkle: Added the screenshot. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to add the 'Virtual Mem' column. Could you add a short explanation of the differences between the two?

Answer (score 0):

MacOS is a UNIX. Thus, it has lots of standard unix tools, in your case, the top program, which you can execute in a terminal.